# Cancelling a Task in threadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I instantiated threadPoolExecutor and submitted asynchronous task to pool and got Future object and then i tried to cancel the task, cancel operation is not working...

The task is related to database calls.

Code is as below,

```
private ThreadPoolExecutor _scheduledThreadPool;
_scheduledThreadPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(_poolSize,   factory);
Future<Object> task = _scheduledThreadPool.submit(task);
tasks.cancel(true);
```

After the above code, I observed the _scheduledThreadPool.getQueue() is giving empty.

I am working on this from few days but not worked.

Please help me how to cancel a task individually in ThreadPoolExecutor.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the task is already running at the time that cancel() is called-- which is what appears to be happening in your case-- then this won't "magically" guarantee that the task will stop running in the way that you expect. The thread running the task will be [interrupted](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_interruption.shtml), and the code performed by your task has to handle this with your desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I want to use remove method and tried as BlockingQueue queue = _scheduledThreadPool.getQueue(); _scheduledThreadPool.remove(runnabletaskFromQueue);

but queue returns empty results.

Please can you give me any suggestions how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's fine to use cancel(), you just need to make sure that your task will actually respond to being interrupted: in other words, that it essentially spends all of its time in calls to methods that are defined as throwing InterruptedException, or that it periodically checks Thread.interrupted() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html

Comment: Yes Now its working.I tried with below  code: 
        try {
            try {                                                         
                process.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                process.cancel(true);
            }
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            process.cancel(true);
        }                                                                    and peridiocally checking  if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) then returning from process. Thank u so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`_scheduledThreadPool.getQueue().clear();`

Comment: please explain why yourr answer solöves the problem. Look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

We have a `Future` object here:

```
Future<Object> task = _scheduledThreadPool.submit(task);
```

`ThreadPoolExecutor` uses `FutureTask` as the default `Future` implementation. And `FutureTask` uses thread interruption [to cancel the task](http://www.javabyexamples.com/task-cancellation-in-java#cancel-with-future). So it invokes `Thread.intterrupt` on the worker thread.

However, for the cancellation to happen, the task must be responsive to interruptions. In other words, it must check whether the current thread is interrupted by invoking `Thread.interrupted`/`Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted`. As an example, we're checking the interruption status in a loop:

```
final Runnable task = () -> {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // Do work.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the task must be blocked on code that respects interruption, like `LinkedBlockingQueue.take`. The standard libraries generally throw an `InterruptedException` when they detect an interruption.